# Getting a tar file for latest linux patches

Tags: tar

```
$ curl -L  https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.0.1.tar.xz | tar -xjkf -

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time Time
Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent  Left  Speed 
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--
0bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child died with signal 13
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
0 78.4M    0 17128    0     0   5499      0  4:09:26  0:00:03  4:09:23
5500
curl: (23) Failed writing body (2152 != 2896)
richard@richard-HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, and the URL indicates, it's not a bzip2 file. It's an xz file, so the option for `tar` should be `-J`, not `-j`:

```
... | tar -xJkf -
```